# Java style FOR loop in a clojure interpeter?

Tags: java, clojure, for-loop, scheme, interpreter

I have a basic interpreter in clojure. Now i need to implement

```
for (initialisation; finish-test; loop-update) {
statements
}
```

inside my interpreter.  I will attach my interpreter code I got so far. Any help is appreciated.

Interpreter

```
(declare interpret make-env) ;; 

(def do-trace false) ;; 

;; simple utilities

(def third ; return third item in a list
 (fn [a-list]
  (second (rest a-list))))

(def fourth ; return fourth item in a list
 (fn [a-list]
  (third (rest a-list))))

(def run ; make it easy to test the interpreter
 (fn [e]
  (println "Processing: " e)
  (println "=> " (interpret e (make-env)))))

;; for the environment

(def make-env
  (fn []
    '()))

(def add-var
  (fn [env var val]
    (cons (list var val) env)))

(def lookup-var
  (fn [env var]
    (cond (empty? env) 'error
          (= (first (first env)) var) (second (first env))
          :else (lookup-var (rest env) var))))

;; -- define numbers

(def is-number?
 (fn [expn]
  (number? expn)))

(def interpret-number
 (fn [expn env]
  expn))

;; -- define symbols

(def is-symbol?
  (fn [expn]
    (symbol? expn)))

(def interpret-symbol
  (fn [expn env]
    (lookup-var env expn)))

;; -- define boolean

(def is-boolean?
  (fn [expn]
    (or
      (= expn 'true)
      (= expn 'false))))

(def interpret-boolean
  (fn [expn env]
    expn))

;; -- define functions

(def is-function?
  (fn [expn]
    (and 
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= 'lambda (first expn)))))

(def interpret-function 
  (fn [expn env]
    expn))

;; -- define addition

(def is-plus?
 (fn [expn]
  (and 
   (list? expn)
   (= 3 (count expn))
   (= '+ (first expn)))))

(def interpret-plus
 (fn [expn env]
  (+ 
   (interpret (second expn) env)
   (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define subtraction

(def is-minus?
 (fn [expn]
  (and 
   (list? expn)
   (= 3 (count expn))
   (= '- (first expn)))))

(def interpret-minus
 (fn [expn env]
  (- 
   (interpret (second expn) env)
   (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define multiplication

(def is-times?
 (fn [expn]
  (and 
   (list? expn)
   (= 3 (count expn))
   (= '* (first expn)))))

(def interpret-times
 (fn [expn env]
  (* 
   (interpret (second expn) env)
   (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define division

(def is-divides?
 (fn [expn]
  (and 
   (list? expn)
   (= 3 (count expn))
   (= '/ (first expn)))))

(def interpret-divides
 (fn [expn env]
  (/ 
   (interpret (second expn) env)
   (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define equals test

(def is-equals?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= '= (first expn)))))

(def interpret-equals
  (fn [expn env]
    (=
      (interpret (second expn) env)
      (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define greater-than test

(def is-greater-than?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= '> (first expn)))))

(def interpret-greater-than
  (fn [expn env]
    (>
      (interpret (second expn) env)
      (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define not

(def is-not?
  (fn [expn]
    (and 
      (list? expn)
      (= 2 (count expn))
      (= 'not (first expn)))))

(def interpret-not
  (fn [expn env]
    (not
      (interpret (second expn) env))))

;; -- define or

(def is-or?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= 'or (first expn)))))

(def interpret-or
  (fn [expn env]
    (or
      (interpret (second expn) env)
      (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define and

(def is-and?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= 'and (first expn)))))

(def interpret-and
  (fn [expn env]
    (and
      (interpret (second expn) env)
      (interpret (third expn) env))))

;; -- define with

(def is-with?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 3 (count expn))
      (= 'with (first expn)))))

(def interpret-with
  (fn [expn env]
    (interpret (third expn)
               (add-var env 
                        (first (second expn))
                        (interpret (second (second expn)) env)))))

;; -- define if

(def is-if?
  (fn [expn]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 4 (count expn))
      (= 'if (first expn)))))

(def interpret-if
  (fn [expn env]
    (cond (interpret (second expn) env) (interpret (third expn) env)
          :else                         (interpret (fourth expn) env))))

;; -- define function-application

(def is-function-application?
  (fn [expn env]
    (and
      (list? expn)
      (= 2 (count expn))
      (is-function? (interpret (first expn) env)))))

(def interpret-function-application
  (fn [expn env]
    (let [function (interpret (first expn) env)]
      (interpret (third function)
                 (add-var env
                          (first (second function))
                          (interpret (second expn) env))))))
```

**;; the interpreter itself**

```
(def interpret
  (fn [expn env]
    (cond do-trace (println "Interpret is processing: " expn))
    (cond 
      ; basic values
      (is-number? expn) (interpret-number expn env)
      (is-symbol? expn) (interpret-symbol expn env)
      (is-boolean? expn) (interpret-boolean expn env)
      (is-function? expn) (interpret-function expn env)
      ; built-in functions
      (is-plus? expn) (interpret-plus expn env)
      (is-minus? expn) (interpret-minus expn env)
      (is-times? expn) (interpret-times expn env)
      (is-divides? expn) (interpret-divides expn env)
      (is-equals? expn) (interpret-equals expn env)
      (is-greater-than? expn) (interpret-greater-than expn env)
      (is-not? expn) (interpret-not expn env)
      (is-or? expn) (interpret-or expn env)
      (is-and? expn) (interpret-and expn env)
      ; special syntax
      (is-with? expn) (interpret-with expn env)
      (is-if? expn) (interpret-if expn env)
      ; functions
      (is-function-application? expn env) (interpret-function-application expn env)
      :else 'error)))
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? To create a for loop in clojure or to create an interpreter in clojure for your own custom language?

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question (not sure what it is), but check out multimethods. They should do well to get rid of that monolithic cond you've got there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't completely sure what the syntax of your interpreted language is, but it looks like you've implemented `lambda` which is all you really need to get a lot of syntactic sugar. You can implement things like `for` loops using `lambda`.

All you really need to do is add a `for-handler` function which parses an expression like:

```
(for (i 0 (< 1 10))
  (print i))
```

into:

```
((lambda ()
   (define (loop i n)
             (if (or (< i n) (= i n))
                 (begin (print i) (loop (+ 1 i) n))))
   (loop 1 10)))
```

and then passes this new expression to `interpret` again. The code above is from my solution to the [SICP Exercise 4.9](https://github.com/spacemanaki/structure-and-interpretation/blob/master/ch4/ex-4.09-iteration.scm)

I didn't spend too much time trying to figure out if your interpreter supports internal defines like this, but it looks like you have `with` which may allow you to do something like this:

```
   (with (loop (lambda (i n)
                 (if (or (< i n) (= i n))
                     (begin (print i) (loop (+ 1 i) n))))
         (loop 1 10))
```

Essentially, you need to expand the `for` expression in an application of a recursive function. The above code defines a function named `loop` and immediately calls it. The outer `lambda` forces the entire expression to run right away.

If you want some more details on this, there is a chapter in the excellent [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1) on building metacircular interpreters, and there are discussions on implementing internal definitions, as well as discussions what they call "derived expressions" which is basically sugar like `for`.

Good luck!

Comment: In Clojure, **lambda** is **fn**.

Comment: I know, but in the OP's interpreted language, the keyword is `lambda`. All the expanded code above would be interpreted, none of it is meant to be Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have found, clojure doesn't have for (though you could implement one) loops.  You just use a simple recursive call like this:

```
(loop [var inital-value]
  ;; statements (regarding "var")
  (when-not finish-test
    (recur update-var)))
```

As long as your `finish-test` evaluates to `false`, `recur` will return execution to the start of `loop` using the value of `update-var` as the new `var`. See http://clojure.org/functional_programming

Comment: Clojure does have a **for** *macro*, http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for

Comment: It has a `for` macro that acts as a list comprehension.  I didn't mention it because it acts nothing like a "Java-style FOR loop" that the asker requested and I didn't want to confuse the issue. What I said was that clojure doesn't have *for loops*.